# Facebook app Publish on admin wall JSSDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-wall

I'm new to FB develop but I've been struggling on this for hours.

I implemented fb comments on my blog and I am trying to make the app notify me everytime someone adds a comment to the blog.

As I've read apps are not allowed to send messages and as I can«t find a way to get the info in the notifications bar the way I feel is acceptable is to get in my wall a post from the app.

I've been working around this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function ()  
{   
   FB.init({  
       appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // App ID  
       status     : true, // check login status  
       cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
       xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML 
       oauth: true  
    });  //end init
             FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (resp) {  
             FB.api('/my id/feed', 'post',  {  message: 'new comment...'},
            function(resp2) {
                if (!resp2 ) {
                     alert('Sem resposta do perfil do admin' + url);
               } else if (resp2.error ){
                    alert('Erro na notificação do admin - '; + resp2.error);// always comes to here
               } else{     alert('Post ID: '; + resp2.id);   }                   });//end api
});//end subscr
};
```

I've been messing around with `fb.login` although that's not the way I want it, and getsetssionstatus as I thought it could have something to do with permissions but got nowhere.

Another quick question, my app is posting the activity on my wall publicly how do I set it , friends only? Can't seem to find my own app in privacy settings.

Comment: You have syntax error in the code:  `id/feed';, 'post'`  Remove the semicolon and it shouldn't error out on that line anymore.

Comment: thx for answering, unfortunally that error was added while creating post. Blogger substitutes the ' caracter with &#39; and I missed correcting that one. The problem doesn't seem tõ be sintax related as the code runs. Added a note to where it stops.

Comment: your callback function is also riddled with syntax errors.  It won't be parsed correctly by the javascript engine of your browser.  Why don't you copy and paste the "real" code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to post. JUst thought it would be better for the app post to its own wall. Got it working. The problem was that I was lacking an access token. Now I have it posting as app to app wall. The problem now is, where did the posts go? When I try to access graph.fecebook.com/appid/feed I get this:

```
"data": [
      {
         "id": "appid_354550067919779",
         "from": {
            "name": "Estou ou Sou comments",
            "canvas_name": "rodcomments",
            "namespace": "rodcomments",
            "id": "appid"
         },
         "message": "Novo coment\u00e1rio no blog...http://estouousou.blogspot.pt/2012/03/definitivamente-este-mes-e-o-culminar.html",
         "type": "status",
         "application": {
            "name": "Estou ou Sou comments",
            "canvas_name": "rodcomments",
            "namespace": "rodcomments",
            "id": "appid"
         },
         "created_time": "2012-03-24T06:37:21+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-03-24T06:37:21+0000",
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         },
         "is_published": true
      }, .........
```

so the post are there...

When I access the page I created for app there's nothing there :( How do I access the app wall?